# How to highlight a cell in Excel using conditional if?

Tags: excel, vba

How can i **conditionally** assign color to cells  ?

I have the following *function* that is supposed to assign different color to cells depending on the if statement:

```
 Function .....
    ..........
    If (IsNumeric(x)  Then
    .Color = 65344                  // does not work
    Else
    ...........
    End If
    End Function
```

How to do this in a correct way?

Comment: You can use any of this method `Range("A1").Interior.Color = vbyellow` or `Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 2` or `Range("A1").Interior.color = Rgb(1,1,1)`

Comment: Is `65344` a correct number for a color?

Comment: maximum allowed ColorIndex value which is 56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what color you are using here because 65344 isn't a hex value, but you can use RGB like this:

```
Function .....
    ..........
    Dim c As Range
    Dim report As Worksheet

    Set report = Excel.ActiveSheet
    Set c = report.Cells(1, 1)

    If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
       c.Interior.Color = RGB(110, 110, 100)
    End If
End Function
```

Here is a better example that may help. (fyi this is free hand so double check it for syntax errors)

```
Sub changeColor()

Dim report as Worksheet

set report = Excel.ActiveSheet

dim i as integer

for i = 0 to 100
    if IsNumeric(report.cells(i,1).value) then
        report.cells(i,1).interior.color = rgb(220,230,241)
    else
        report.cells(i,1).interior.color = xlNone
    end if
next i
end sub
```

Comment: You could also use `.Interior.ColorIndex = (value)` [Resource](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-cell-background-color-using-vba-HA001136627.aspx) + [Colors in Excel](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm)

Comment: Thank You. I like the first example. However, ` .Interior.Color = RGB(101,52,64)` does not do the job. I get a message `invalid qualifier`

Comment: @AlekseiNikolaevich The invalid qualifier error is occuring because you are calling `.Interior.Color` without referencing a range. You need to do something like `Cells(1,1).Interior.Color`. First, I removed the extra opening parenthesis from the If statement. Next, you have to make sure that x = the value of the cell in question (not the cell itself). Then, when you change the color, just prefix the range object before the `.Interior.Color`. The range object can be a cell or range of cells for which you want to change the interior color.

Comment: @AlekseiNikolaevich you need to qualify the Range object. Use x.Interior.Color